# Find the largest value for the contour integral

Tags: complex-analysis

find an upper bound for $$\int_{C} z^{-5} dz$$ where $C=[C_1,C_2,C_3]$. $C_1$ is the line segment from $-1-i$ to $1-i$, $C_2$ is the line segment from $1-i$ to $i$, and $C_3$ is the line segment from $i$ to $-1-i$.

Attempt: using parametrizations I found the length of $C$ to be $2 \sqrt{5}+2$. Next I found that the shortest distance from the origin to the contour to be $\frac{1}{2}$. So $|z|^5\geq \frac{1}{2^5}$ and $|z|^{-5} \leq 2^{5}$.

So I said $$|\int_{C} z^{-5} dz| \leq 2^5(2 \sqrt 5 +2)$$but the answer in the book was $5^{5/2}(2 \sqrt 5 +2)$.

Where have I got wrong. I thought I was supposed to look for the shortest distance from the origin to the contour. Then take the reciprocal of that value to the fifth power to get an upper bound for $|z|^{-5}$?

Comment: The equations for the two slant edges are $y \pm 2x = 1$ and their closest distance to origin equals to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{(\pm2)^2+1^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$. The minimum is reached at $\frac{\pm 2 + i}{5}$.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum distance is $5^{-1/2}$. 
Therefore  $|\int_Cz^{-5}\operatorname dz|\le \int_C|z^{-5}|\operatorname dz\le 5^{5/2}(2\sqrt5+2)$.

To compute that min, minimize $|(x,-2x+1)|=\sqrt{x^2+4x^2-4x+1}$.

So we'll square it and use some calculus.  Differentiate $5x^2-4x+1$, getting $10x-4$.  Then $x=2/5$ is the critical point.  Plugging it in, we get $1/\sqrt5$.

Comment: How should I get started?

Comment: See my edit please.

Comment: Where are you getting $2^{1/2}$? I thought the shortest distance to the contour would be from the origin along the $x$ axis and I tried using similar triangles to show that the length is $1/2$?

Comment: My bad.  Because of the reciprocal it would be the shortest.  Let's double check it.

Comment: Yea I don't think $1/2$ would be the shortest distance or would it?

Comment: Although I haven't calculated it it looks like the shortest distance has to be $1/ \sqrt 5$ based on the books answer

Comment: Yes.  See my new edit.